# NamedBuildTarget.Unknown is invalid type for PlayerSettings.SetApiCompatibilityLevel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to do:

```
// Set PlayerSettings API Compatibility Level to always be .NET Framework
PlayerSettings.SetApiCompatibilityLevel(UnityEditor.Build.NamedBuildTarget.Unknown, ApiCompatibilityLevel.NET_Unity_4_8);
```

However I'm getting:

```
ArgumentException: The provided target platform group name () is not valid.
UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.SetApiCompatibilityLevel (UnityEditor.Build.NamedBuildTarget buildTarget, UnityEditor.ApiCompatibilityLevel value) (at <4f41070b52224a70bdc90f923c6b37de>:0)
```

Here are the relevant DOCS:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.NamedBuildTarget.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.SetApiCompatibilityLevel.html

I want to be able to set the API Compatibility Level "blindly" because all device platforms we support are compatible with the desired target .NET API.

I am able to do that with the Icons, like this:

`PlayerSettings.SetIcons(UnityEditor.Build.NamedBuildTarget.Unknown, new Texture2D[] .......`

Is there a solution that matches what I'm looking for or will I have to use an individual line of code for each build target?

Thanks,
Mauricio

Comment: what sense does it make to manually set the target build platform for Unknown? ... Afaik you need to either use the current actual build target or iterate them

Comment: Ok, first, I am not setting the build target. I am setting the Api Compatibility level.

PlayerSettings.SetIcons, has a kind of 'catch-all' behavior when the BuildTarget is unknown, as other methods in PlayerSettings also do, for the purpose of you not having to iterate and also it is more readable, rather than asking the current and setting the current again. Why is it not the case for this one?

This is in order to try and control mistakes that might happen when someone is manually building, to prevent ProjectSettings from being altered and have control.

Comment: Fair points, I see now! It makes even less sense tbh because for the images you will find very different settings for each platform ... the API Compatibility level is **shared** between all! It is only stored **once** in `ProjectSettings/PlayerSettings.asset -> apiCompatibilityLevel` ... so it shouldn't matter at all what platform is passed ^^ The obsolete property simply uses current (and you should as well): `SetApiCompatibilityLevel(EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetGroup, value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tbh it is a bit weird. The API Compatibility Level is actually **shared** between all! It is only stored **once** in

```
ProjectSettings/PlayerSettings.asset -> apiCompatibilityLevel
```

so it shouldn't matter at all what platform is passed.

There is an obsolete property that simply uses current:

> ```
> [Obsolete("apiCompatibilityLevel is deprecated. Use PlayerSettings.GetApiCompatibilityLevel()/PlayerSettings.SetApiCompatibilityLevel() instead.")]
> public static ApiCompatibilityLevel apiCompatibilityLevel
> {
>     get { return GetApiCompatibilityLevel(EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetGroup); }
>     set { SetApiCompatibilityLevel(EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetGroup, value); }
> }
> ```

You could/should do the same - **HOWEVER**, `EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTargetGroup` is `internal` within `UnityEditor`.

You can workaround this by using e.g.

```
var buildTarget = EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget;
var targetGroup = BuildPipeline.GetBuildTargetGroup(buildTarget);
var namedBuildTarget = UnityEditor.Build.NamedBuildTarget.FromBuildTargetGroup(targetGroup);
  
PlayerSettings.SetApiCompatibilityLevel(namedBuildTarget, ApiCompatibilityLevel.NET_Unity_4_8);
```

Alternatively you could also use a [Bridge Assembly](https://discussions.unity.com/t/how-to-access-useful-unity-editor-engine-internal-methods/251479) (internals of `UnityEditor` are exposed to specifically named assemblies like e.g. `Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge001` up to `Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge024` using [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute))

---

Hm further playing around I found there is also `ProjectSettings/PlayerSettings.asset -> apiCompatibilityLevelPerPlatform`. This only lists those platforms that explicitly have been assigned a different Api Compatibility Level from the global one. This can either happen via code or the PlayerSettings Inspector.

So it seems there is no other way of totally ensuring it is set for all than either rely on doing it for the current platform as soon as the platform was switched (see [`IActiveBuildTargetChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IActiveBuildTargetChanged.html))

```
public int callbackOrder { get; } = 0;
public void OnActiveBuildTargetChanged(BuildTarget previousTarget, BuildTarget newTarget)
{
    var targetGroup = BuildPipeline.GetBuildTargetGroup(newTarget);
    var namedBuildTarget = UnityEditor.Build.NamedBuildTarget.FromBuildTargetGroup(targetGroup);
  
    PlayerSettings.SetApiCompatibilityLevel(namedBuildTarget, ApiCompatibilityLevel.NET_Unity_4_8);
}
```

or iterating them all - as far as I remember the latter will yield uncatchable errors though in case certain targets are not installed.

Comment: Thank you derHugo this is very insightful!!